# Open HREF in new window using JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a URL to an anchor/div using JS. I have implemented the following code but it will only open the URL in the same window.

```
 var href = document.getElementById("mainwrapper");
 href.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://www.ebay.com/\'');'
```

Whats the best way to open in target using this method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the second argument of the window.open() function to do that.

```
var href = document.getElementById("mainwrapper"); 
href.addEventListener("click", handleOpen);

function handleOpen(){
   window.open('http://www.ebay.com','_blank');
}
```